# Passing a variable from one file into another as a class variable after inline modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was wondering whether its possible to get a variable (basically  a list) from one python file into the main program file and then pass it into a class object in the main program file without first defining the variable (WORDS below) in the program file. I will explain the situation below. 
File words.py has a list named wordlist. I import this wordlist into the main program file main.py like:

```
# words.py file
wordlist = ['an',''..] # some list of words

# main.py
from words import wordlist

WORDS = wordlist.copy()
WORDS.remove('an')

mc = models_class(word_list = WORDS)
```

As i have tried the above works if i first define a local variable WORDS but can it work if i directly pass the wordlist into the class object and apply remove there, like below.

```
mc = models_class(word_list = wordlist.remove('an'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do like `word_list = wordlist.remove('an')` because `remove` is an in-place operation which just update the original list and return None.

See [python more on list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – `they return the default None`. 1 This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, you are right i did notice the None being returned if i try to print and see the output of remove. I  just didn't knew that the reason for that was because these are in-place operations as you explained. Thanks!!