# Python List Append not working on sliced lists

Tags: python, list, append, slice

I have a list a = [1,2,3,4,5]

I don't understand why the following code doesn't produce [2,3,4,5,1]

```
a[1:].append(a[0])
```

I tried reading up on the append() method as well as list slicing in Python, but found no satisfactory response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[1:]` gives you a whole new `list`, but you're not assigning it to any variable so it it just thrown away after that line. You should assign it to something (say, `b`) and then append to it (otherwise `append` would change the list but return nothing):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a[1:]
b.append(a[0])
```

And now `b` is your desired output `[2,3,4,5,1]`

Comment: In op's case, it would probably would be cleaner to write `a = a[1:] + a[:1]`

Comment: @flakes I agree but he wanted an explanation about slicing and how `append` works

Comment: I agree. *Cleaner* was not the right word choice on my part. Not trying to take anything away from your response!

Comment: @flakes that's OK you are right to point that out, it's good to teach OP another way of looking at it as well

Comment: @flakes your piece of code works (it is exactly what I resorted to), but I wanted to know why the append wasn't working like I'd used. Ofer cleared it up :)

Answer (score 1):

I think here you just not really understand `append` function. Just like my answer in [Passing a variable from one file into another as a class variable after inline modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222178/passing-a-variable-from-one-file-into-another-as-a-class-variable-after-inline-m/58222356#58222356), `append` is an in-place operation which just update the original list and return None.

Your chain call `a[1:].append(a[0])` will return the last call return value in the chain, so return `append` function value, which is None.

Just like @flakes comment in another answer, `a[1:] + a[:1]` will return your target value. Also you can try `a[1:][1:][1:]` which will return some 
 result. So the key point is the `append` function is in-place function.

See [python more on list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – `they return the default None`. 1 This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

Answer (score 0):

First, append the first element a[0] to the list

```
a.append(a[0])
```

and then exclude the first element

```
a[1:]
```